# meaning of percent symbol in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST HOST column

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I'm running a query against INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST (shown below). The HOST column in the result is showing %:port_number instead of ip_address:port_number.

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
where 1=1
and COMMAND <> 'Sleep';
```

What is the meaning of the percent symbol (is it just, MySQL can't figure it out?), and why does it not show the incoming IP address?

Answer (score -1):

The '%' character is a wildcard that will match any host.

Comment: Process list, not grants